# red5 client disconnection not working :S

Tags: red5

I've been using Red5 0.9.0.1, and im trying to disconnect a flash client app from my red5 server app. I've achived to manually disconnect the client by using close(); on my flash app. but I cant just achieve to disconnect the user when the user closes the windows explorer, or the user looses its internet connection.
any suggestion on how to do this? can someone guide me to the right path?

Answer (score 0):

The red5 server method disconnect does exactly this.

you need to override it and it will look like this...

```
@Override
public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you must use an onUnLoad() handler to then call into your Flash client app. The call should then close the NetConnection; this is the "cleanest" way to do it. Otherwise on the server side, the I/O library will detect and handle the disconnection (peer disconnect).